# Animating element property with transitions

Tags: css

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3b293012/1/)

Im trying to animate my pop up menu.

I have this on the offscreen ul element:

```
top: 40px; //hidden off bottom of page
-webkit-transition: all .8s ease;
-moz-transition: all .8s ease;
-ms-transition: all .8s ease;
-o-transition: all .8s ease;
transition: all .8s ease;
```

And on hover I:

```
bottom: 40px;
top: auto;
```

But it's not animating - why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because your `bottom` property isn't initialized in the class.

Change this

```
#filter >ul >li >ul{
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
...
```

To This

```
#filter >ul >li >ul{
position: absolute;
top: 40px;
bottom: 0;
...
```

**[Fiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/3b293012/2/)**

Your properties should be initialized to a "default value" to do a correct animation. Just do some tests yourself with different properties and you'll find out.

---

As the **OP** said, this breaks his *wanted* animation ( althought the question was why the code was not animating )

`top` and `bottom` are two opposite properties and, by the animation you want, you should consider a comprimise. **[Like this one](http://jsfiddle.net/3b293012/3/)**

Just remove `top` and set `bottom` default value to a low negative value, then animate to `bottom: 0` on hover.

I personally do not like this, but it works. You should pay attention to that default value: If you add more `<li>` to your menu, you'll have to calculate that again.

Comment: Thanks but this breaks the original code - now the pop up goes no higher than its parent.

Comment: @panthro Your question was `But it's not animating - why?` and you know why. `top` and `bottom` can't work properly togheter you might want to find a comprimise. I'll update the answer